# A triangle $ABC$ is given with $AB=8,BC=9,AC=13$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry

A triangle $ABC$ is given with $AB=8,BC=9,AC=13$. The vertex $A$ lies on the plane $\alpha$ and $BC\parallel \alpha$. A line $p$ through the midpoint of $AC$ and $B$ intersects $\alpha$ in $D$. Find the length of $BD$.

> $BD=11$

I am new to solid geometry and it's difficult for me to imagine the figures. I am really used to plane geometry. Can you help me with the diagram? I am not sure if we can use these formulas here, but if $K$ is the midpoint of $AC$, then $BK$ is a median of the triangle $ABC$, so $$m_b=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2a^2+2c^2-a^2}=\dfrac{11}{2}.$$ What can I do from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

We know the plane $\alpha$ is parallel to $BC$ and so the line $AD$ is parallel to $BC$ (line $AD$ is in the same plane as $\triangle ABC$).

If $K$ is the midpoint, $\triangle AKD \cong \triangle CKB$ given $BC \parallel AD$ and $CK = AK$.

So $BD = 2 \cdot BK = 11$

**EDIT:** On your question on why $BC \parallel AD$, say $\triangle ABC$ is in plane $\beta$. The key point is that the line through points $A$ and $D$ are in both planes $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Now it comes down to using the following properties of Euclidean space  - **(i)** If a line and a plane are parallel, they never meet. As line through $B, C$ and plane $\alpha$ are parallel, they never meet and this implies lines through $B, C$ and through $A, D$ never meet **(ii)** If two lines in the same plane never meet, they are parallel. So lines through $B, C$ and through $A, D$ being in the same plane $\beta$ must be parallel.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I didn't get why $AD$ is parallel to $BC$.

Comment: Say $\triangle ABC$ is in plane $\beta$. Now $AD$ is formed at intersection of plane $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and is in both planes. We already know plane $\alpha$ is parallel to $BC$ so $AD$ will be parallel to $BC$.

Comment: May I ask you why $D$ lies on $\beta=(ABC)$?

Comment: Because it is on a line through points $A$ and $K$ and points $A$ and $K$ are in plane $\beta$. A straight line is defined by two points. In other words, is is possible to draw a line through two points on a plane which goes out of the plane? Let me know if it is clear.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! You mean the points $B$ and $K$, right?

Comment: So $\alpha\cap\beta=AD$ and the two planes have common line determined by the points $A$ and $D$?

Comment: But are we using a theorem here, because I can't see it in my book. How does this mean that $AD\parallel BC$?

Comment: If one of two intersecting planes is parallel to a line, then the intersecting line is also parallel to this line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120653/discussion-between-math-lover-and-idoktorova).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to draw it in order to understand it better, so here it is[image]

From here you can deduce that the triangles $KCB$ and $KAD$ are similar because of the criteria $ASA$.Can you finish it?

Comment: Thank you for the diagram! It is a really good one even though it is made by hand.

Comment: thank you, I hope I had helped you